# Can plugging a Galaxy S6 directly into the outlet short circuit it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I just bought the S6 whch cost me $800 so I really want to know if the technology has advanced enough that I can charge my phone using a Blackberry travel charger without using a surge protector?  I remember reading that spikes in electricity could damage electronics right?  I usually use the Belkin mini USB travel hub but I don't have it right now and I really need to charge the phone but I don't want to risk damaging the phone in any way. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your area, how often do you have a power surge and how bad is it? A quality charger/adapter should level out most minor spikes. I have had a lot of electronics and phones and never seen one damaged by a power surge, but that may just be me being lucky. Nothing can really guarantee that it is going to be 100% safe, a sufficiently large surge will fry any surge protectors anyway.

Comment: @Lie Ryan I don't know how often. Do the lights have to flicker for it to be considered a "severe" surge?

Answer (score 0):

With any power surge it just depends on how bad the power surge is. But yes. It is possible for a power surge to go through a charger and damage the phone. My suggestion would be, Buy a travel size surge protector to carry with you if you are really worried about it. Or buy one of those power banks and charge your phone off of it. Now a days you can pick up a 15,000 mAh one pretty cheap. With a 15k one, you should be good for at least 4-5 charges(since most banks arent 100% efficient) on the S6 since its battery is only 2550 mAh.

Comment: What do you mean good for 4-5 charges?   Power bricks only protect for a limited amount of time? Hmm, is "power bank" different?

Comment: Oh sorry, What I mean is the power bank would charge the phone 4-5 times before you would have to recharge the power bank. -Edit- Something like this, is what I am talking about. http://www.amazon.com/KMASHI-15000mAh-Ultra-High-External-Motorola/dp/B00JP8MZGK

Comment: Now if my battery pack is charging using the wall...will charging the phone at the same time connected to the battery pack be safe or can any surges go through the charging battery pack through to the phone?

Comment: With anything you plug into the wall there is the chance that a powerful enough surge can go through anything, Just depends on how bad the surge is. I am just wondering but do you experience power surges often?

But with those battery packs. They recommend that you dont charge it and charge your phone at the same thing. To much heat from charging and discharging can damage the battery.

Comment: You mean damage the battery back or the phone's battery?  How do I know when there is a power surge?

Comment: The battery pack. Cause you are sending energy to it while drawing energy from it. Causes extra heat. And heat is a battery's worst nightmare. At least that's what i have read on plenty of websites

Comment: Sorry didnt see the second part. This might help ya. http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/surge-protector3.htm